# How to know the virtual address of the data & code in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, architecture, operating-system

1. How can one get the virtual address of the data & code in a program?

   One might say use `%u` or `%p` or something else.

   ```
   printf("%u", &data);
   printf("%p", &data);
   ```

   I'm always confused; which one gives correct address? Both give addresses but what's the difference?
2. Is there any way we can say which part of memory a given virtual address belongs to? Can we identify that it's a stack address or a heap address or something else?

Comment: Always use `%p` for pointers. Pointer and `unsigned int` are not always the same size.

Comment: What exactly with "_p The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner._" don't you understand? And what is unclear with "u The unsigned int argument ..."? Enable compiler warnings and get your code to compile without any warning.

Comment: And C does not even mention  virtual or physical addresses. That is nothing an application has to even think about.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: And dont' ask Operating System question with the C or C++ tags or you'll get put on hold.

Answer (score 2):

For (1) *Only* `printf("%p", &data)` can be used to print the pointer address although you **must** write `(void*)&data` (C-standard ref C11, 7.21.6.1p8), the behaviour of `printf("%u", &data)` is *undefined* as the format specifier is invalid for a pointer type. But note that the address you see may well not have any correspondence to a *physical* address; many operating systems and runtimes place one or two levels of abstraction between physical addresses and the pointer values you see.

For (2), the `printf` call is also valid in C++.

For (3), neither the C nor the C++ standard (aside from a couple of standard library functions in the latter) have a notion of a *stack* or a *heap*, so, no, there is no portable way of telling.

Answer (score 0):

1. You may not use `%u` specifier to print a pointer. That specifier is for `unsigned int`. `%p` is the correct format specifier for pointers. The difference is that using `%u` is technically undefined behaviour because the argument is of a different type than is required. Furthermore, you must cast `&data` to `void*`.
2. Indeed, `printf` is in the c library portion that is included in c++ standard library so you may use it. But if you prefer c++ streams, then you can use `std::cout << &data;`
3. That is not possible in standard c++ (nor in c).

In neither standard, is there is distinction between virtual and physical memory. There is just memory. Whatever addresses of that memory represent is specified by the OS. If the program does not run in an OS that uses virtual memory, then the addresses may physical.

Comment: The addresses could be various recipes for chicken soup, if that's what the platform/OS used.

Answer (score 0):

From the rest of your questions, it suggests you are trying to use C++ to identify pedagogical concepts that have no real existence in running code.

> How can one get the virtual address of the data & code in a program?

The linker assembles code and data into program segments. There can be multiple program segments containing either. However, the default is usually to have one of each. If you want to find that information, you need to create a linker MAP file as part of your program build and read that.

As you want to do that in the code, you would need to write something that parsed the contents of the executable file.

Your operating system may have system services that you can use to inspect pages to see  (a) if they are valid and (b) what their attributes are. From that you could determine where code resides.

> I'm always confused; which one gives correct address? Both give addresses but what's the difference?

%p is correct for pointers. %u is correct for unsigned integers. On most systems they are effectively the same. However, on some they are not (i.e., sizeof (int) != sizeof (int*), or the pointer has a weird format as on segmented intel).

Use %p for pointers.

> How can we get the same virtual address details in C++? (Since it is downward compatible with C, we can use same thing, but is there any other way?)
>
> Is there any way we can say which part of memory a given virtual address belongs to? Can we identify that it's a stack address or a heap address or something else?

Memory is just memory. As a teaching tool, memory is often described in terms of data/heap/stack. That does not exist in reality. A heap and a stack are simply blocks of memory that are managed in different ways. A heap can be a stack.

Comment: _"On most systems they are effectively the same."_ That hasn't been true for years, has it? 64-bit dominates now (at least in the consumer market) but on modern 64-bit platforms `int` still tends to be 32-bit.